# Laravel 5: Method [postPreview($id)] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

I would be very grateful if you could help me solve this problem.

I wrote a route:

```
Route::get('/{id}','PostsController@postPreview($id)');
```

Function in PostsController:

```
public  function postPreview($id)
    {

        if ( $id ){

        $post = Post::find($id);
          }
        return view('index')->with('post', $post);
    }
```

And in view index:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Vijesti</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Komentari za vijesti">
</head>

<body>
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>


{!! $post !!}
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting error: BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 283:
Method [postPreview($id)] does not exist.

Comment: drop the `$id` in `postPreview($id)` @ the route part. leave it simply as `Route::get('/{id}','PostsController@postPreview');`

Comment: It still doesn't work:(
FatalErrorException in PostsController.php line 91:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Post' not found

Comment: `Post` vs `Posts` perhaps

Comment: Route::get('/{id}','PostsController@postPreview');
Controller is PostsController and the model is Post.
I don't get it..

Comment: include your Post model `use App\path_to_model`

Comment: @dyachenko I fixed it:D I just had to add  `\App\Post` in `$post =Post::find($id);`
Thanks a lot on your time, folks:)